# why this mysql create table (with multiple types) have error

Tags: mysql

why this query doesn't work?! I look just ok.

isn't ok not to give any type size?

[image]

Comment: The error states the issue is with the table already existing - suggesting the problem is with the sql verification system used by whatever course you're taking, as opposed to your code.

Answer (score 1):

you can read why in the last row of your screenshot

it is pretty eloquent:

> Sql error: table products already exists

Answer (score 0):

try to change the table name,it telling already exist it seems ..

and even try to provide for Description varchar(200),stack_count integer